# Why is using git with && failing when inside a .sh but not from the command line?

Tags: bash, scripts, git

I have a script (called `update_content.sh`) that is supposed to run 3 consecutive `git` commands and the first version looked like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
git fetch --all && git reset --hard && git merge
```

When I run it I see this output:

```
web@bane:~# ./update_content.sh
Fetching origin
error: unable to create file locales/fr.json (File exists)
error: unable to create file locales/it.json (File exists)
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.
```

However when I changed it to this:

```
#!/bin/sh
git fetch --all
git reset --hard
git merge
```

And run it I see this:

```
web@bane:~# ./update_content.sh
Fetching origin
HEAD is now at 5859b2e Added Business tab
Already up-to-date.
```

The newline approach gets the result I want however it does not have the "don't proceed if a step failed" quality of the `&&`.  Is there something about how `git` works that makes it incompatible with the `&&` or am I missing something about `&&`?

I did a little more digging and found that the one liner with `&&` when run from the command line doesn't throw errors but also doesn't actually reset the local working copy, however the new line approach inside a script (and run one at a time) does.

Comment: shouldn't your question be on unix.SE though?

Comment: I can move it if you think it has a better shot over there

Comment: I have to wait 40 minutes before the other stackexchange site will let me post,

Answer (score 3):

You may as well create an alias to chain all the commands and then execute the alias object itself.

```
git config alias.op '!git fetch --all && git reset --hard && git merge'
git op
```

`&&` only runs the second command if the first one exited with status 0 (was successful). `;` runs both the commands, even if the first one exits with a non zero status.

Your example with `&&` can be equivalently paraphrased as

```
if git fetch --all ; then
    if git reset --hard; then
       git merge
    fi
fi
```

Comment: I understand this aspect of `&&`, the strange thing to me at least is why when I run the 3 commands with `&&` then `git reset --hard` is failing, however when I run them in their own lines the same command is succeeding (not producing any error, also I tried `;` and the `reset` command still failed (though because of `;` it now attempted to run `git merge`)

Comment: It is because while the first process of fetching the branch is running, the next command `git reset --hard` gets executed simultaneously which in turn results into a conflict.

Comment: I don't think `&&` runs simultaneously (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command)

Comment: My bad! Please check the updates and check if that works out for you.

Comment: I had no idea that was possible.  I'll try it but I don't like the idea of configuring git in that way, it seems like a config option like that would get lost as this project changed hands.  Still a fascinating approach.

Comment: It works. I tried it myself right now. And, aliases are stored in git config files, which include ~/.gitconfig and path/to/project/.git/config. As a result, it's possible to store aliases in a per-project as well as a global state. So, you can don't have to worry about losing the changes.